# android checked item in dialog call function one time only

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I created an alertDialog that contains list with chechbox looks somehow like this is image

[image]

I want when select multi-items to delete them from sqlite and this is the code of alert

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete: {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < azkarItems.length; i++) {
                            if (itemsChecked[i]) {
                deleteZekr(azkarIds[i], mySQLiteAdapter, azkarItems[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(azkarItems, itemsChecked,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), azkarItems[which] + (isChecked ? "checked!" : "unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }

        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is the body of deleteZekr() function

```
public void deleteZekr(int dZekrID, SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter, String zekr) {

    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
    mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

    System.out.println("the zeker to delete: "+zekr);
    mySQLiteAdapter.delete_byID(dZekrID);

    mySQLiteAdapter.close();

    setDataInList(mySQLiteAdapter);
}
```

The problem is that it calls this method only one time, meaning if I decided to delete the first 2 items, it deletes only one item.

Any Solution? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I might be missing something but where do you add the items to the itemsChecked list?

Comment: I added them in sqlite.

Comment: I guess I meant where do you add to this list, `azkarIds`? Shouldn't they be added when you check on one? If you check 2 items, what is the value of `azkarItems.length`?